# What's the best way to lock multiple std::mutex'es?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, deadlock

Note: This question concerns C++11. The answer to the same question in C++17 (or later revisions) may have changed. For details:

- [std::lock_guard or std::scoped_lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019598/stdlock-guard-or-stdscoped-lock)

---

When we want to lock multiple `std::mutex`'es, we use `std::lock()`. But `std::lock()` does not provide RAII feature.

When we want to lock a `std::mutex` in RAII way, we use `std::lock_guard`. But `std::lock_guard` cannot lock multiple `std::mutex`'es safely.

Is there any way to take the advantages of both methods, to lock multiple `std::mutex`'es in RAII way?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `std::unique_lock` with [`std::defer_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag). It tells the unique_lock to not lock the mutex immediately, but to build the RAII wrapper.

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(mutex1, std::defer_lock);
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(mutex2, std::defer_lock);
std::lock(lk1, lk2);
```

Due to its variadic nature `std::lock` is not bound to only two arguments but can be used with as many arguments as your compiler has support for.

Howard Hinnant also pointed out an interesting fact about performance, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13667810/893693) link if you are interested. He addresses performance concerns and shows that `std::lock` can be implemented efficiently, I can also recommend to read all the comments in that post.

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out, `std::lock_guard` in itself doesn't provide a deadlock-free way of locking multiple mutexs. Without a safe method, you run into the [Dining Philosophers Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

[`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) implements a deadlock-free algorithm which locks multiple *[Lockable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Lockable)* objects.
It can be used with

- [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and [`std::adopt_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag), and with
- [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [`std::defer_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag).

```cpp
std::mutex m1, m2;

{   // Option A - lock mutexes first, adopt later
    std::lock(m1, m2);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock1(m1, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock2(m2, std::adopt_lock);
    // critical section ...
}

{   // Option B - defer first, lock locks later
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(m1, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(m2, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(lock1, lock2);
    // critical section ...
}

{    // Option C - std::scoped_lock (C++17, but provided here for completeness)
    std::scoped_lock lock(m1, m2);
}
```

If you don't need the extra features that `std::unique_lock` provides (e.g. transferring ownership of the lock elsewhere), then `std::lock_guard` should be preferred.

---

*Note: the examples show only two locks, but all methods work with arbitrarily many locks.*