# What special purpose does unique_lock have over using a mutex?

Tags: c++, c++11, threadpool, mutex, stdthread

I'm not quite sure why `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` is useful over just using a normal lock. An example in the code I'm looking at is:

```
{//aquire lock

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

        //add task
        tasks.push_back(std::function<void()>(f));

}//release lock
```

why would this preferred over

```
queue_mutex.lock();

//add task
//...

queue_mutex.unlock();
```

do these snippets of code accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Think about an exception thrown between `lock/unlock` calls in your latter sample ...

Comment: The following link might be of interest to you once you have understood this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516773/stdunique-lockstdmutex-or-stdlock-guardstdmutex/20516876#20516876

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> [Do] these snippets of code accomplish the same thing?

No.

The first one will release the lock at the end of the block, no matter what the block is. The second will not release the lock at the end if the critical section is exited with a `break`, `continue`, `return`, `goto`, exception, or any other kind of non-local jump that I'm forgetting about.

Comment: Beat me to it!  I would also add that there's significant advantage to std::unique_lock in respect to RAII.  Assume that a method inside a mutex throws before unlock() is called.  The mutex could potentially never unlock. std::unique_lock is guaranteed to release even if an exception is thrown where-as std::mutex will not (since unlock must be called manually).

Comment: IOW, the first one actually *does* what most people are hoping for when they write the second.

Comment: So would it be wise to always opt to use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` whenever applicable in the future?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose  I would say yes.  It's a bit safer all in all.

Comment: @SyntacticFructose In almost all cases.  There are a few (very rare) cases where you want the lock to live beyond the end of the block.  (I've put the `unlock` in the deleter object of a `shared_ptr`, for example.)

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: In most cases, a simple `std::lock_guard` should actually suffice. It's generally a good idea to use the simplest possible type to achieve a certain task.

Answer (score 5):

The use of `unique_lock` offers resiliency in the face of changes and errors.

- If you change the flow to add intermediate "jumps" (`return` for example)
- If an exception is thrown
- ...

in any case, the lock is *automatically* released.

On the other hand, if you attempt to do it manually, you may miss a case. And even if you don't right now, a later edit might.

---

Note: this is a usual idiom in C++, referred to as SBRM (Scoped Bound Resources Management) where you tie down a clean-up action to stack unwinding so you are assured that, unless crash/ungraceful exit, it is executed.

It also shows off RAII (Resources Acquisition is Initialization) since the very construction of `unique_lock` acquires the resource (here the mutex). Despite its name, this acronym is also colloquially used to refer to deterministic release at destruction time, which covers a broader scope than SBRM since it refers to *all kind* of deterministic releases, not only those based on stack unwinding.