# alternately running threads + waiting for multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, condition-variable

This is my first question here, so if I am not precise enough, tell me and I will try to elaborate.

Consider the following program:

I have equally many threads of two functions `void a()` and `void i()`.

Each thread of `a()` performs some calculation on a different set of data in a loop and the corresponding thread of `i()` performs another calculation on the same data (again in a loop).

The functions`a()` and `i()` have to run alternately, but `a()` has to wait for all threads of `i()` to finish (one cycle of the loop), before it is supposed to resume. Every thread of `i()` only has to wait until the corresponding thread of `a()` finished the calculation.

```
void a(int N, datatype data){
   for (int j = 0; j != N; j++){
      //wait until all threads of i() are finished
      //calculate something with data
      //notify i()
      }
   }

void i(int N, datatype data){
       for (int j = 0; j != N; j++){
          //wait until corresponding thread of a() is finished
          //calculate something with data
          //notify a()
          }
       }
```

I am familiar with the standard-library's condition variables and locks. 
Still, I do not know, how to achieve the behaviour described above.

I tried it with a little test-program, which only prints out data, but the output is not what it is supposed to be.

The test-program:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int O = 2;
const int N = 2;
mutex m, n;
condition_variable a_finished[O];
condition_variable i_finished;
bool i_done[O];


bool check(bool* b){
  bool tmp = true;
  for (int j = 0; j != O; j++){
    if (b[j] == false){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

void printR(const char* c, int p){
  lock_guard<mutex> lockg(n);
  cout << c << p << " running!\n";
}

void print(int j, const char* c, int p){
  lock_guard<mutex> lockg(n);
  cout << c << p << ": " << j << "\n";
}

void a(int N, int p){
  printR("a", p);

  for (int j = 0; j != N; j++){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    i_finished.wait(lock, [&](){return check(i_done); });
    //cout << check(i_done) << "\n";
    print(j, "a", p);
    lock.unlock();
    a_finished[p].notify_all();
  }
}

void i(int N, int p){
  printR("i", p);
  i_done[p] = true;
  for (int j = 0; j != N; j++){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    a_finished[p].wait(lock);
    i_done[p] = false;
    print(j, "i", p);
    i_done[p] = true;
    lock.unlock();

    i_finished.notify_all();
  }
}



int main() {

  for (int c = 0; c != O; c++){
    i_done[c] = false;
  }

  thread a_threads[O];
  thread i_threads[O];

  for (int c = 0; c != O; c++){
    a_threads[c] = thread(a, N, c);
    i_threads[c] = thread(i, N, c);
  }
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
  i_finished.notify_all();

  for (int c = 0; c != O; c++){
    a_threads[c].join();
    i_threads[c].join();
  }
}
```

The output should be something like:

```
i0 running!
a0 running!
i1 running!
a1 running!
a0: 0
a1: 0
i0: 0
i1: 0
a1: 1
i1: 1
a0: 1
i0: 1
a1: 2
a0: 2
i0: 2
i1: 2
...
```

i.e. the confirmation that all threads are running,
then each thread of `a()` before the corresponding thread of `i()` (for every step; until N is reached).

Instead, I get this:

```
a0 running!
i0 running!
a1 running!
i1 running!
a1: 0
a1: 1
i1: 0
a0: 0
a0: 1
i0: 0
```

*How could I implement this / where is my mistake?*

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It would be nice if the code you posted compiled.

Comment: "`f2` has to wait for corresponding `f1`" part is easiest to implement by having `f1` perform both calculations, one after another; since they must be sequential, there is no reason to have them in different threads. "All computations have to complete before starting a new cycle" part calls for a [synchronization barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999911/what-is-the-best-way-to-realize-a-synchronization-barrier-between-threads)

Comment: fixed it to compile @PaulSanders