# Software Barriers in C++

Tags: c++, barrier

Is there a way to enforce ordering in GCC so computations before a barrier are ordered before computations after the barrier in assembly code?

I was reading some Linus Torvald correspondences and he mentions a Barrier() macro but I can't find it in GCC.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to realize a synchronization barrier between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999911/what-is-the-best-way-to-realize-a-synchronization-barrier-between-threads)

Comment: The order of assembly code doesn't determine the order of execution or evaluation.  Are you sure that is what you want?  C++ has a concept called "happens before", and that makes actual guarantees in the abstract machine that C++ behavior is specified in.  It is possible that is what you want?  (It makes no direct guarantees about generated assembly, just about abstract machine behavior)

Comment: Yes, I want to limit the order of assembly code as in my question.

Comment: https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/memory_barriers.html