# What's the difference between first locking and creating a lock_guard(adopt_lock) and creating a unique_lock(defer_lock) and locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

I have found the following 2 pieces of code:

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock

   ```
   void assign_lunch_partner(Employee &e1, Employee &e2)                                                                                                  
   {   
       // use std::lock to acquire two locks without worrying about 
       // other calls to assign_lunch_partner deadlocking us
       {   
           // m is the std::mutex field
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::defer_lock);
           std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::defer_lock);
           std::lock(lk1, lk2);
           // ...
       }   
   }
   ```
2. [http://www.amazon.com/C-Concurrency-Action-Practical-Multithreading/dp/1933988770](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770)

   ```
   void swap(X& lhs, X&rhs){                                                                                                                              
     if(&lhs == &rhs)
       return;
     // m is the std::mutex field
     std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m);
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
     swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);
   }
   ```

I wanted to ask what is the difference and consequence of using either of 2 versions? (first lock or first create the [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)?)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**1)** First code sample

```
{   
    static std::mutex io_mutex;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(io_mutex);
    std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " are waiting for locks" << std::endl;
}
```

This is a standard lock guard, when the scope is exited, the lock `lk` is released

```
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(lk1, lk2);
    std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " got locks" << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

Here we first create the locks without acquiring them (that's the point of [`std::defer_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag)) and then, using [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) on both locks simultaneously makes sure that they are acquired without the risk of a deadlock if another caller of the function interleaves (we could have a deadlock if you replaced it with two successive calls to `std::lock` :

```
{   
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(e1.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(e2.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(lk1);
    std::lock(lk2); // Risk of deadlock !
    std::cout << e1.id << " and " << e2.id << " got locks" << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

**2)** Second code sample

```
void swap(X& lhs, X&rhs){                                                                                                                              
  if(&lhs == &rhs)
    return;
  // m is the std::mutex field
  std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m);
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
  swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);
}
```

Now, here we first acquire the locks (still avoiding deadlocks), and *then* we create the lockguards to make sure that they are properly released.

Note that [`std::adopt_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) requires that the current thread owns the mutex (which is the case since we just locked them)

---

**Conclusion**

There are 2 patterns here :

1) Lock both mutex at the same time, then create the guards

2) Create the guards, then lock both mutex at the same time

Both patterns are equivalent, and aim at the same thing : safely lock two mutex at the same time, and ensure that unlocking always occur for both.

As for the difference between `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`, you should see [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516773/stdunique-lockstdmutex-or-stdlock-guardstdmutex), most of the time `std::lock_guard` is enough.

Comment: From the conclusion section which one you will recommend?
If both are equivalent then there should be some thinking that both patterns exist.
Can you point out the cases where we can use one over another?

Answer (score 9):

There's actually a paragraph (3.2.6) in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) explaining that the code is virtually equivalent and you could replace one with the other. The only difference being is that `std::unique_lock` tends to take more space and is a fraction slower than `std::lock_guard`.

Bottom line is whenever you don't need the additional flexibility that `std::unique_lock` provides, go with `std::lock_guard`.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is robustness against future changes. In the `adopt_lock` version there is a window where the mutexes are locked but not owned by a cleanup handler:

```
std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m);
// <-- Bad news if someone adds junk here that can throw.
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
```

It's also possible to accidentally remove/omit one of the guard declarations without any compile-time errors. The problem will be obvious at runtime when the deadlock hits, but it's not fun to trace a deadlock back to its source.

The `defer_lock` version doesn't suffer from either of these problems. Since the guard objects are declared *before* the locking happens, there's no unsafe window. And of course if you omit/remove one of the guard declarations you'll get a compiler error at the `std::lock` call.

Comment: In C++17, [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) would solve both problems even more elegantly.