# How to use lock_guard in this conditional

Tags: c++, multithreading

A thread has the following control flow:

```
mutex.lock()
if (condition) {
    // do synced things
    mutex.unlock();
    // do parallel things
} else {
    // do other synced things
    mutex.unlock();
    // do other parallel things
}
```

Note how the four `do` parts all execute different things.

How do I replace direct calls to lock and unlock into using `std::lock_guard` instead?

Comment: Does `condition` need to be in the scope of the mutex lock?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes it must be locked when accessed.

Comment: Personally, I would use `unique_lock` and still unlock the mutex manually. You get both RAII and control over the unlock process

Comment: @KABoissonneault That is the cleanest way to do it IMHO.  It keeps you from having multiple if's like Xarn's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unique_lock` looks like what you're looking for. Semantics are similar to `std::lock_guard`, but [allows more sophisticated constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20516876/168175). So in your case you still get the exception safety, but also can explicitly unlock early. Something like:

```
std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)> guard(mutex); // calls mutex.lock() like lock_guard
if (condition) {
    // do synced things
    guard.unlock();
    // do parallel things
} else {
    // do other synced things
    guard.unlock();
    // do other parallel things
}
// unlocks on leaving scope, if held similar to lock_guard
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool cond;
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
    cond = global_condition;
    if (cond){
        // do some synced stuff
    } else {
        // do the other synced stuff
    }
}

if (cond){
    // do parallel stuff
} else {
    // do the other parallel stuff
}
```

since the parallel stuff in both the cases is done after unlocking mutex guarding the global condition, it means that the condition either cannot change, or we don't care if it changes. Thus we can save the value and if-else again later based on the saved value.