# Manage Lock mutually exclusive

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have two static function

```
namespace
{
 std::mutex mtx;
}

//static
static void func1()
{

}

//static
static void func2()
{
}
```

func1 & func2 are mutually exclusive in different threads.
If i want to use std::mutex to manage the call what should be the best to use?
`std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`?

Comment: can you share the duplicate reference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516773/stdunique-lockstdmutex-or-stdlock-guardstdmutex