# std::scoped_lock or std::unique_lock or std::lock_guard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, c++17

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019598/stdlock-guard-or-stdscoped-lock) question I understand that `std::scoped_lock` is "a strictly superior version of `std::lock_guard`".

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516773/stdunique-lockstdmutex-or-stdlock-guardstdmutex) question I understand that "`std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` are the same" except that `std::unique_lock` has some extra features (eg. [`try_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock)) at the cost of some additional overhead.

**How does `std::scoped_lock` compare with `std::unique_lock`?**

Some related questions that I am hoping to get answered by this question.

1. What are the differences between `std::scoped_lock` and `std::unique_lock`?
2. In what situations should you use `std::scoped_lock` instead of `std::unique_lock`?
3. In what situations should you use `std::unique_lock` instead of `std::scoped_lock`?
4. Why does `std::scoped_lock` not implement some of the additional features of `std::unique_lock`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The two objects are for different purposes. `scoped_lock` is for the simple case of wanting to lock some number of mutex objects in a deadlock-free way. Locking a single mutex is just a special case of locking multiple ones. The object is completely immobile, and it's very simple.

`unique_lock` provides a number of features, few of which are especially applicable when simultaneously locking *multiple* mutexes.

- Deferred locking. Deferring would have to be all or nothing; you either defer locking all the mutexes or none of them. It's not clear why you would want to defer locking a series of mutexes, since you would have to relinquish any locks that succeeded if any of them failed.
- Timeout locks. If you want a timeout of 100ms, does that mean that locking all of the mutexes should take no more than 100ms? That is, if the first 3 lock immediately, but the next one takes 75ms, should it be considered a timeout if the fifth takes 30ms?
- Adoption of mutexes. The whole point of locking multiple mutexes in a single operation is to be able to avoid deadlocks. This is done by locking the mutexes in an order that is *globally* consistent. That is, any place where you lock those mutex objects with `std::lock` equivalent calls will lock them in the same order, no matter what.

  If one of the mutexes has already been locked (and thus the lock should be adopted), then it was locked outside of `std::lock`, and thus you have no guarantee that it was locked in the globally consistent order. And that ignores the difficulty of specifying which mutexes to adopt and which ones to lock.
- Transfer of ownership (being moveable). This is a dubious prospect for multiple mutexes for similar reasons as adopting locks. The guarantees against deadlocks only work if a single call to `std::lock` or equivalent locks all of the mutexes of interest. If you're moving ownership of these `scoped_lock`s around, it becomes very easy to be at a point in code where you have multiple `scoped_lock`s in the same scope, when you could have locked all of them in one go. This courts the very kind of deadlock that `std::lock` was created to avoid.

Note that `std::lock` (the basis of `scoped_lock`'s functionality) doesn't even try to provide any of these features.

Could there be a specialization of `scoped_lock` which took only one mutex type that offered the behavior of `unique_lock`? Sure. But that would violate the purpose of `scoped_lock`, which was to be a deadlock-safe locker for multiple mutexes. It only obsoleted `lock_guard` by accident, since it had the identical interface in the case of a single mutex.

Besides, having template specializations with vastly different interfaces and capabilities doesn't usually work out well. See `vector<bool>` as an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "immobile"?

Comment: @lachy: If something can move, it is said to be "mobile". Therefore, something is "immobile" if it cannot move.

Comment: I think the more standard nomenclature is "moveable," and this is the name of the concept going forward: moveable<T>, though mobile/immobile is cute, but maybe less clear.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer scoped_lock over unique_lock?

Comment: @hddh: It should never be a question which one to use: if you're locking multiple mutexes, you use `scoped_lock`; if you're locking a single mutex, use `unique_lock`.

Comment: fwiw, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172828/4117728) makes some good points to explain why `lock_guard` is not deprectated