# std::lock_guard or std::scoped_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, c++17

C++17 introduced a new lock class called [`std::scoped_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock/scoped_lock).

Judging from the documentation it looks similar to the already existing `std::lock_guard` class.

What's the difference and when should I use it?

Comment: See also: [`std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` or `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20516773/4561887)

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Late answer, and mostly in response to:

> You can consider `std::lock_guard` deprecated.

For the common case that one needs to lock exactly one mutex, `std::lock_guard` has an API that is a little safer to use than `scoped_lock`.

For example:

```
{
   std::scoped_lock lock;  // protect this block
   ...
}
```

The above snippet is likely an accidental run-time error because it compiles and then does absolutely nothing.  The coder probably meant:

```
{
   std::scoped_lock lock{mut};  // protect this block
   ...
}
```

*Now* it locks/unlocks `mut`.

If `lock_guard` was used in the two examples above instead, the first example is a compile-time error instead of a run-time error, and the second example has identical functionality as the version which uses `scoped_lock`.

So my advice is to use the simplest tool for the job:

1. `lock_guard` if you need to lock exactly 1 mutex for an entire scope.
2. `scoped_lock` if you need to lock a number of mutexes that is not exactly 1.
3. `unique_lock` if you need to unlock within the scope of the block (which includes use with a `condition_variable`).

This advice *does* *not* imply that `scoped_lock` should be redesigned to not accept 0 mutexes.  There exist valid use cases where it is desirable for `scoped_lock` to accept variadic template parameter packs which may be empty.  And the empty case should *not* lock anything.

And that's why `lock_guard` isn't deprecated.  `scoped_lock` *and* `unique_lock` may be a superset of functionality of `lock_guard`, but that fact is a double-edged sword.  Sometimes it is just as important what a type *won't* do (default construct in this case).

Comment: "There exist valid use cases where it is desirable for scoped_lock to accept variadic template parameter packs which may be empty". What are those cases?

Comment: The author of `scoped_lock` Mike Spertus showed me such a case in the hall between meetings a couple of years ago.  I'm afraid I don't remember the details well enough to replicate it.  And after a quick search I don't find an example online nor in one of Mike's papers.  If you desperately need an example I recommend contacting Mike directly.

Comment: hi Howard, what if one needs to signal a condition variable within a multiple mutex transaction? I'm thinking that the right approach would be to capture N-1 locks first with `scoped_lock`, then the last with `unique_lock` , retry them all if the last one fails, or do the transaction and signal the condition with the unlockable one

Comment: It is hard to know for sure without more details.  But my first guess at the best tools would be a `condition_variable_any` waiting on a `scoped_lock<M, ...>`.

Comment: A note about the scoped_lock "typo" bug: today I learned that GCC has a warning flag called "-Wparentheses" that can detect that kind of typo. The warning is enabled with "-Wall". [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 216):

The `scoped_lock` is a strictly superior version of `lock_guard` that locks an arbitrary number of mutexes all at once (using the same deadlock-avoidance algorithm as `std::lock`). In new code, you should only ever use `scoped_lock`.

The only reason `lock_guard` still exists is for compatibility. It could not just be deleted, because it is used in current code. Moreover, it proved undesirable to change its definition (from unary to variadic), because that is also an observable, and hence breaking, change (but for somewhat technical reasons).

Comment: Also, thanks to class template argument deduction, you don't even have to list out the lockable types.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That's true, but that also applies to `lock_guard`. But it certainly makes the guard classes a bit easier to use.

Comment: scoped_lock is C++17 only

Comment: As it is c++17, compatibility is a particularly good reason for its existance. I also vehemently disagree with any absolutist claim of "you should only ever use" when the ink is still drying from this standard.

Comment: [Howard Hinnant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60172828/2323908) explains why `scoped_lock` is NOT a strictly superior version of `lock_guard`. The reason for keeping `lock_guard` is not _solely_ due to compatibility!

Comment: @JoakimThorén: Thanks, that's a good point. I don't think this was considered during the design of `scoped_lock`, which started out as a proposal to extend `lock_guard`, but had to be renamed because of ABI breaking concerns. But that's a good insight.

Comment: If it's like this, why wasn't it marked as deprecated?

Answer (score 154):

The single and important difference is that `std::scoped_lock` has a variadic constructor taking more than one mutex. This allows to lock multiple mutexes in a deadlock avoiding way as if `std::lock` were used.

```
{
    // safely locked as if using std::lock
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex, std::mutex> lock(mutex1, mutex2);     
}
```

Previously you had to do a little dance to lock multiple mutexes in a safe way using `std::lock` as explained [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113619/whats-the-best-way-to-lock-multiple-stdmutexes/17113678).

The addition of scope lock makes this easier to use and avoids the related errors. You can consider `std::lock_guard` deprecated. The single argument case of `std::scoped_lock` can be implemented as a specialization and such you don't have to fear about possible performance issues.

GCC 7 already has support for `std::scoped_lock` which can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/g/LPj8BY).

For more information you might want to read the [standard paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0156r2.html)

Comment: Answered your own question after only 10 min. Did you really not know?

Comment: @Walter I did https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Ruslan not sure what you mean. There was no 10 minutes delay. When you create a question you can already provide the answer.

Comment: Ah, right, I believed the comment by Walter without checking times.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if `scoped_lock lk;` turns out to be a bug or a feature.

Comment: @HowardHinnant good point, I think libc++ has an assert that checks for empty template list? https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/mutex#L512 -- nvm, missed the empy specialization. What's that even supposed to do?

Comment: When I brought it up in committee, the answer was "nothing."  It may be that the degenerate case of some algorithm, this is exactly the right thing.  Or it may be that enough people accidentally lock nothing when they intended to lock something is a common problem.  I'm really not sure.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: `scoped_lock lk; // locks all mutexes in scope`. LGTM.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  `scoped_lock lk;` is the new shorthand for `scoped_lock<> lk;`.  There **are** no mutexes. So you're right. ;-)

Comment: @inf Not sure where they got the "...as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy" bit from as it would be in the opposite order.

Comment: Note that you don't need to provide template arguments for `scoped_lock`. It is available since C++17, where template arguments can be deduced for classes.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a sample and quote from *C++ Concurrency in Action*:

```
friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
{
    if (&lhs == & rhs)
        return;
    std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
    swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);
}
```

vs.

```
friend void swap(X& lhs, X& rhs)
{
    if (&lhs == &rhs)
        return;
    std::scoped_lock guard(lhs.m, rhs.m);
    swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);
}
```

> The existence of `std::scoped_lock` means that most of the cases where you would have used `std::lock` prior to c++17 can now be written using `std::scoped_lock`, with less potential for mistakes, which can only be a good thing!