# (Shared) mutex in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++17, mutex

I've seen an example for a shared mutex:

```
class MyData {
    std::vector<double> data_;
    mutable shared_mutex mut_;   // the mutex to protect data_;

public:
    void write() {
        unique_lock<shared_mutex> lk(mut_);
        // ... write to data_ ...
    }

    void read() const {
        shared_lock<shared_mutex> lk(mut_);
        // ... read the data ...
    }
};
```

Naturally I would have written instead:

```
public:
    void write() {
        mut_.lock();
        // ... write to data_ ...
        mut_.unlock();
    }

    void read() const {
        mut_.lock_shared();
        // ... read the data ...
        mut_.unlock_shared();
    }
};
```

Is my way also correct? And is there a difference between what I used and what was used in the example? Also, are there advantages of one over the other? Thank you!

Comment: Just a side note: If you write `auto lk = unique_lock(mut_);` you can make your code a bit more generic (there is no need for the template argument in that case), and you don't need to worry about of what type `mut_` is, it just needs to meet the requirements `unique_lock` has on the Mutex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is my way also correct?

Consider what would happen if the code between the locking of the mutex and  the unlocking throws an exception:

```
void write() {
    mut_.lock();
    // <-- exception is thrown here
    mut_.unlock();
}
```

The mutex then remains locked.

> are there advantages of one over the other?

Yes, `unique_lock<>` follows the [RAII idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), and therefore unlocking of the mutex is handled automatically (i.e., by its destructor) in case of an exception:

```
void write() {
    unique_lock<shared_mutex> lk(mut_);
    // <-- exception is thrown
}
```

In case of an exception after the creation of the `unique_lock<shared_mutex>` object – `lk` – its destructor is called, and it then unlocks the associated mutex if it was locked (remember that `std::unique_lock`, unlike `std::lock_guard`, doesn't always have ownership of the lock on the associated mutex – see [`std::defer_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag) and [`std::unique_lock::unlock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock)).

To sum up, with `lock_guard`/`unique_lock`/`shared_lock`, no special handling is required from your side in case of exceptions or when leaving the member function from different execution paths.

Comment: Thanks. One more question if you don't mind: unique_lock<shared_mutex> lk(mut_); locks from the beginning of the function until its end, right? And: the "lk" is the name of the lock then?

Comment: @BenC. `unique_lock<shared_mutex> lk(mut_);` locks the mutex as soon as it is constructed. In this case, at the very beginning of the function. `lk` is the name of the `unique_lock<shared_mutex>` object.

Comment: So it unlocks the mutex automatically when the function is done?

Comment: @BenC. It unlocks the mutex automatically – if it is locked, in your case, it is – at destruction, when `lk` is destroyed. I would suggest you have a look at [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) as well. `std::unique_lock` is more flexible, but it looks that don't need that flexibility.

Comment: Note that since C++17, [`std::scoped_lock` is highly preferred over `std::lock_guard`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019598/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, good point, indeed `std::scoped_lock` renders `std::lock_guard` obsolete. Not so, however, with `std::unique_lock` because it implements `unlock()` whereas `std::scoped_lock` doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Raw mutex is generally avoided in favour of the RAII version unique_lock(), which is safer in two situations:

- exception
- premature return

Like raw pointer are generally avoided in favour of RAII version smart pointers: unique_ptr or shared_ptr.

Either case, the RAII version ensure that the mutex (or pointer) is always released when the it goes out of scope.