# std::scoped_lock behaviour with a single mutex

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, mutex, scoped-lock

**Context:**

I know that `std::lock_guard` became kind of deprecated since the arrival of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with `std::scoped_lock`.

I also know that `std::scoped_lock` is preferred since it can handle several mutexes and uses a deadlock avoidance algorithm the same way as `std::lock` does.

I'm interested here in the case we have only one single mutex and thus we don't need to care about deadlock avoidance.

I have read from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43019599/11455384) that:

> You can consider `std::lock_guard` deprecated. The single argument case of `std::scoped_lock` can be implemented as a specialization and such you don't have to fear about possible performance issues.

**Question:**

I'm wondering how much this sentence is true.

I mean, is it guaranteed (by the standard) that with a single mutex, `std::scoped_lock` will be specialized so that it will get rid of any unnecessary overhead due to deadlock avoidance handling ?

---

**My thoughts:**

After some investigation on the question, I found from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) the following sentence:

> If several mutexes are given, deadlock avoidance algorithm is used as if by `std::lock`.

Which could let us deduce that such a thing would not happen otherwise (i.e. if only one mutex is given).
But once again, it is just an assumption.

From this [c++ draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#thread.lock.scoped) I don't see any explicit mention about such a specialization.
The only sentence I got is:

> When `sizeof...(MutexTypes)` is `1`, the supplied `Mutex` type shall meet the *Cpp17BasicLockable* requirements. Otherwise, each of the mutex types shall meet the *Cpp17Lockable* requirements.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

I know that the *BasicLockable* requirements mandate the existence of `lock()` and `unlock()` functions which meet the conditions such as defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable).
On the other hand, the *Lockable* requirements assume the *BasicLockable* requirements with the addition of a `try_lock()` function which meet the conditions such as defined [there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Lockable).

I know that the `try_lock()` function is required in order to run the deadlock avoidance algorithm used by `std::lock`.

From what's stated in the above [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) draft extract, the `try_lock()` function is thus not required if we give only one mutex to `std::scoped_lock`.
Is this sufficient to deduce/consider that the above specialization is always defined (and presumably behaves as `std::lock_guard` would do).
I would say yes but as I never saw any explicit mention about it, I wonder if I'm right or if I missed something ?

---

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that I missed the most important part [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#thread.lock.scoped-3) which states:

> *Effects*: Initializes `pm` with `tie(m...)`. Then if `sizeof...(MutexTypes)` is `0`, no effects. Otherwise if `sizeof...(MutexTypes)` is `1`, then `m.lock()`. **Otherwise, `lock(m...)`**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Which answers my interrogations, `std::lock` is called only when there is more than one given mutex. I should have seen it before asking the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the specification of `lock_guard` (which is right above `scoped_lock`) it should be clear.

[[thread.lock.guard]-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#thread.lock.guard-3)

> Initializes pm with m. Calls m.lock()

[[thread.lock.scoped]-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#thread.lock.scoped-3)

> Initializes pm with tie(m...). [...] Otherwise if sizeof...(MutexTypes) is 1, then m.lock(). [...]

It doesn't explicitly mention to use `lock_guard` but it is required to have the same behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this part quite too late (mentioned in my edit).

Answer (score 4):

`std::scoped_lock` is required to behave identically to `std::lock_guard` when only one mutex is supplied. Hence the different requirement for the single mutex case.

This could be done with a specialization, or it could be done via a different internal mechanism, as long as the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. Actually I missed the most [important part](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#thread.lock.scoped-3). I should have noticed it before asking my question :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard will seldomly guarantee some kind of optimization though specialization (Notable examples are specializations on different iterator typea and the abomination which is `std::vector<bool>`). For this there are two ways to go at it:

1. Trust your compiler/standard library implementation. Compilers are epic, they do extremely advanced kinds of optimization, some of them you can only dream of. The implementations of the STL are in most cases fantastic. There are areas where they are slower since they have to be able to handle weird edge cases, but here there has to be a different specialization already since only BasicLockable is required for the one argument case, so it will have an implementation that does not need `try_lock`, so why shouldn't it be efficient.
2. Perform your code. Test if it is fast enough, test if `scoped_lock` is on a hot path of your code and if you really think (and have data to prove it) that `scoped_lock` is slow, then and only then replace it  with `lock_guard` and test again.

Comment: Agreed, but I cannot rely on possible compiler optimizations to issue a general compiler-independent certainty. The only guarantees I can trust are the ones given by the standard. The underlying question was that I wanted to know if I could completely get rid of `std::lock_guard` with the guarantee that it will not incur any unnecessary overhead with only one mutex.