# Should I use lock_guard, scoped_lock or unique_lock in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++17, mutex, lock-guard

I have read many of the questions already answered that relate to this but none of them gave me a clear understanding of which I should be using when I have multiple writers but a single reader.  The code below is a contrived example of what I'm talking about.

```
struct StateInfo {
    long wd{};
    uint32_t perc{};
};

class Blah 
{
    const int numDevices = getDevices();
    std::shared_mutex sharedMutexSI_;
    vector<StateInfo> stateInfo;
public:

    Blah() : stateInfo(numDevices){};

    void writers(StateInfo &newSi, const int i)
    {
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> _MULTIPLE(sharedMutexSI_);
        stateInfo[i] = newSi;
    }

    StateInfo reader(const int i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::shared_mutex> _EXCLUSIVE(sharedMutexSI_);
        return stateInfo[i];
    }
};
```

The situation is that multiple writers may simultaneously update the stateInfo vector but never the same item in the vector as `i` is unique to each thread.  A single reader thread may at any time try to read any of the vector items.

1. Is the above code correct in avoiding race conditions?
2. Is `lock_guard` the right one to use or should I use `scoped_lock` or `unique_lock`?

Comment: There is no difference between `lock_guard`, `scoped_lock` and `unique_lock` in this use case

Comment: Depending on the size of `long` on your platform you could change `StateInfo` to `std::atomic<uint64_t>` and avoid locking all together

Comment: @AlanBirtles so `lock_guard` is the right one as it is the simplest and the others don't add anything useful in this case?

Comment: Seems in 17 lock_guard is unfavoured or supersetted by scoped_lock?

Comment: Both, `lock_guard` and `scoped_lock` are fine, `unique_lock` is an overkill.

Comment: My understanding is that `lock_guard` is the simplest and if I don't need the functionality of `scoped_lock`, then I should stick with the simplest?

Comment: At least in libstdc++, for a single mutex `lock_guard` and `scoped_lock` are identical in their implementation.

Comment: If (number of readers) times (number of writers) to X is positive (i.e. `> 0`) all readers and writers of X must be synchronised. Then it depends on how many synchronisation primitives (e.g. mutex) is acceptable. With exactly one primitive, all readers and writers must use it (so all writers synchronise with each other and the reader). If `n` mutexes (`n` = number of elements) is acceptable, then each writer can use its own primitive (and not synchronise with other writers) but the reader must grab the corresponding primitive before reading each element (i.e. synchronise with all writers).

Comment: Regarding `lock_guard`, `scoped_lock` and `unique_lock`: see a dedicated question with answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019598/509868).

Comment: You use `shared_lock` for writing and `scope_lock` for reading? That is opposite of what you want. Use `shared_lock` for reading and `scope_lock` for writing.

Comment: @ALX23z, OP has one reader and several writers, and there are no data races between writers.

Comment: @Evg you mean he has writers dedicated to each index? This is a presumption made outside of class which isn't good in general. In this case it might be preferable to have each state info have its own `std::mutex` or just make the `StateInfo` atomic. In any case the class suffers from false-sharing so I am not sure if shared lock helps much.

Comment: @ALX23z, yeah, that's what Alan Birtles and Peter suggested above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize what was already written in comments:

Yes, the code is correct. However, it may be inefficient, because it disallows reading from any array element while writing to another array element. You might want to do more fine-grained synchronization by using a `mutex` for each array element.

```
class Blah 
{
    const int numDevices = getDevices();
    std::vector<std::mutex> mutexes;
    std::vector<StateInfo> stateInfo;
public:

    Blah() : mutexes(numDevices), stateInfo(numDevices){}

    void writers(StateInfo &newSi, const int i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutexes[i]);
        stateInfo[i] = newSi;
    }

    StateInfo reader(const int i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutexes[i]);
        return stateInfo[i];
    }
};
```