# Multithreading in n-ary tree

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex

I have tried to use multithreading in n-ary tree in the lock_it() function. Saw all the tutorials present. But i am unable to come up the code. I only able to remove the deadlocks but i want to maximize the parallel running of  lock_it() function.

Read at this link to know what lock_it() does.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/locking-and-unlocking-of-resources-in-the-form-of-n-ary-tree/

How to improve it?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    char key;
    bool locked;
    int cnt_locked_desc;
    Node* parent;
    vector<Node*> child;
};
Node* root = NULL;
mutex mtx;
```

```
class LockUnlock {
public:
Node* newNode(char node_key, Node* prt) {
        Node* tmp = new Node;
        (*tmp).key = node_key;
        (*tmp).locked = (*tmp).cnt_locked_desc = 0;
        (*tmp).parent = prt;
        return tmp;
    }
    bool lock_it(Node* node) {  //O(h)
        if ((*node).cnt_locked_desc > 0 || node == NULL)
            return 0;
        for (Node* curr = node; curr != NULL; curr = (*curr).parent)
            if ((*curr).locked)
                return 0;
        mtx.lock();
        for (Node* curr = node; curr != NULL; curr = (*curr).parent) {
            (*curr).cnt_locked_desc++;
        }
        mtx.unlock();
        (*node).locked = 1;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Save yourself some typing and instead of `(*t).` just do `t->`.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Concurrency is a tough subject. If you're interested in learning more on it, I really enjoyed this book: https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition

Comment: And this course: https://www.udemy.com/course/modern-cpp-concurrency-in-depth/

Comment: okay i will read them. but how can i approach to it.

Comment: It's unclear from the code what `mtx` is.  Is that a per-tree mutex or a per-node mutex or a global mutex or what?

Comment: Maybe describe what the lock_it function actually does so it's easier to reason about

Comment: its just mutex.. okay i am adding full code

Comment: Why do you set `locked` *outside* of the mutex lock? That seems risky. You may want to look into [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: Hey @Yamahari i have added the description for lock_it()

Comment: @tadman actually i learnt about mutex today.

Comment: Looks like you are traversing the tree bottom to top but top down seems to be way better as there is 0 shared data except the root if you split each child of the root into a seperate thread

Comment: @Yamahari how to do that?  Whenever i am at a node i have create a thread?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using a `scoped_lock` index of directly using the mutex.

[std::lock_guard or std::scoped_lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019598/stdlock-guard-or-stdscoped-lock)

Concurrency is a tough subject. If you're interested in learning more on it, I really enjoyed this book: https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition

And this course: https://www.udemy.com/course/modern-cpp-concurrency-in-depth/

I also highly recommend this course: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2018/

Comment: for now can you answer some approach to the question

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer is that there's no short answer for concurrency. It takes a lot of study to undertand and use well. There are a lot places where you can hang yourself and, unfortunately, it requires serious study to get right. If you're interested in using concurrency in c++ effectively, I encourage you to invest the time in reading that book (and MIT course if you're open to going further).