# When should `std::scoped_lock` be used over `std::shared_lock`?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

When should `std::scoped_lock` be used over `std::shared_lock`?
I don't think I understand the use of `std::scoped_lock`.

Or, is `std::scoped_lock` just a variant of `std::unique_lock` for holding multiple mutexes?
Ref: "[std::lock_guard or std::scoped_lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019598/stdlock-guard-or-stdscoped-lock)"

Comment: Did you read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread ? What part of their description did you not understand?

Comment: Its completelly different things. `std::shared_lock` is used with one shared mutex and `std::scoped_lock` is used with multiple usual mtexes,