# c++ std::scoped_lock Caller failing to hold lock 'lock' before calling function 'func'

Tags: c++, mutex

In my project I'm returning a std::scoped lock to guard some resources.

A very simple example is this

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <mutex>


class A
{
    public:
    static auto getLock();
    private:
    inline static std::recursive_mutex s_mutex;
};


auto A::getLock()
{
    return std::scoped_lock(s_mutex);
}

void unguardedFunction()
{
    //access shared resources here
}

void guardedFunction()
{
    auto lock = A::getLock();
    //access shared resources here
    unguardedFunction();
}

int main()
{
    guardedFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Now visual studio warns me, that the lock cannot be held before the end of unguardedFunction().
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26110?view=msvc-170

Is this a false positive of Visual Studio 2022?
If not can you tell me why? I thought std::scoped_lock is movable?

The Internet did suggest to replace std::scoped_lock with std::lock_guard. But isn't std::scoped_lock a safer wrapper around std::lock_guard?

thx guys for your explanations.

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite [`std::lock_guard` is safer to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019598/stdlock-guard-or-stdscoped-lock). But it can only lock one single mutex while `std::scoped_lock` can do more.

Comment: None of `std::lock_guard` and `std::scoped_lock` are movable (nor copyable). And returning one of them from a function seems wrong. I don't know how things will do with copy elision (wich is probably the only reason why such code still compiles) but for me, your lock is a temporary, released when the function exits. It's probably undefined behaviour to do so (but it's only a guess).

Comment: really? SOnarlint allways tells me to replace std::lockguard with std::scped_lock

Comment: Yes a lot of people falsely say that `std::lock_guard` is deprecated, which is not the case actually. `std::scoped_lock` is a more powerful object, with more features. But as everything, with more power comes more responsibility :p If you need to lock only one mutex, `std::lock_guard` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Fareanor This is a C++17 code, where we have deferred temporary materialization. No copy or move constructor is involved here. Modified for C++14, it wouldn't compile regardless of the copy elision: https://godbolt.org/z/afTYqxqEj.

Comment: The static analysis tool is probably confused by your, shall we say, unorthodox way of grabbing a lock. See if it's happier with something like `std::scoped_lock lock(A::getMutex());` where `A::getMutex()` returns a reference to `s_mutex`