# How does std::lock work with std::unique_lock objects instead of directly with std::mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, unique-lock

I'm working with a piece of multithreading code that involves bank account transfers. The goal is to safely transfer money between accounts without running into race conditions. I'm using `std::mutex` to protect the bank account balances during transfers:

My question centers around the use of `std::unique_lock` with `std::lock`. Instead of passing the `std::mutex` objects directly to `std::lock`, I'm wrapping them with `std::unique_lock` and passing those to `std::lock`.

How does `std::lock` work with `std::unique_lock` objects?

Is `std::lock` responsible for actually locking the `from` and `to` mutexes, while the `std::unique_lock` objects merely manage the locks (i.e., release them when they go out of scope)?

Does `std::lock` call the `lock()` method of `std::unique_lock`?

What is the advantage of using `std::unique_lock` with `std::lock` over directly passing `std::mutex` objects to `std::lock`?

```
struct bank_account
{
    bank_account(int balance) :
        mtx(), balance{ balance }

    {}
    std::mutex mtx;
    int balance;
};

void transfer(bank_account& from, bank_account& to, int amount)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> from_Lock(from.mtx, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> to_Lock(to.mtx, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(from_Lock, to_Lock);
    
    if (amount <= from.balance)
    {
        std::cout << "Before:    " << amount << " from: " << from.balance << " to: " << to.balance << '\n';
        from.balance -= amount;
        to.balance += amount;
        std::cout << "After:     " << amount << " from: " << from.balance << " to: " << to.balance << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << amount << " is greater than " << from.balance << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    bank_account A(200);
    bank_account B(100);
    std::vector<std::jthread> workers;
    workers.reserve(20);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        workers.emplace_back(transfer, std::ref(A), std::ref(B), 20);
        workers.emplace_back(transfer, std::ref(B), std::ref(A), 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read cppreference's docs on [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [`std::lock()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) yet?

Comment: I did read but that's what exactly I wanted to know in the answer below which I couldn't find it in the resource:
"when objects of std::unique_lock are passed to std::lock, the std::lock function calls the lock() method of each std::unique_lock object. This, in turn, locks the associated mutex. In this scenario, due to std::defer_lock, the mutex isn't locked directly upon the creation of the std::unique_lock object. Instead, it's locked via the std::lock function."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) is to provide a deadlock free locking (see [libc++ implementation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/18b67243550a4f2ef12cc2d93a12f5bfecb50752/libcxx/include/mutex#L404-L454)) of multiple *Lockable* objects.
The classic problem is that if you have two locks **L1** and **L2**, and

- one thread locks **L1** and then **L2**, and
- another thread locks **L2** and then **L1**,

then there may be a deadlock because each thread could hold one lock and require the other from another thread. This issue applies when you're locking `from.mtx` and `to.mtx` in:

> ```cpp
> std::unique_lock<std::mutex> from_Lock(from.mtx, std::defer_lock);
> std::unique_lock<std::mutex> to_Lock(to.mtx, std::defer_lock);
> std::lock(from_Lock, to_Lock);
> ```

`std::lock` does the deadlock-free locking of `from_Lock` and `to_Lock`, and `std::unique_lock` does the rest (i.e. RAII stuff).

### Q&A

> How does `std::lock` work with `std::unique_lock` objects?
> Does `std::lock` call the `lock()` method of `std::unique_lock`?

`std::unique_lock` is *Lockable*, and `std::lock` will call `lock()` on it, which then `lock()`s the mutex.

> Is `std::lock` responsible for actually locking the `from` and `to` mutexes, while the `std::unique_lock` objects merely manage the locks (i.e., release them when they go out of scope)?

`std::unique_lock` is perfectly capable of doing locking and unlocking a mutex on its own. The only thing it can't do is implement a deadlock free locking when multiple locks are involved.

> What is the advantage of using `std::unique_lock` with `std::lock` over directly passing `std::mutex` objects to `std::lock`?

You would have to manually unlock both mutexes afterwards, and this is bug-prone. It's a similar problem as `std::unique_ptr` vs. `new`/`delete`. It would be fine if you immediately wrapped both mutexes in a `std::lock_guard` though.

### Further Improvements

For use with `std::lock`, you could use a simpler lock than `std::unique_lock`:

```cpp
std::lock(from.mtx, to.mtx);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> from_lock(from.mtx, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> to_lock(to.mtx, std::adopt_lock);
```

You only need `std::unique_lock` if you want to transfer ownership; otherwise you can use `std::lock_guard` (which is a slightly simpler type).

If you're using C++17, things get even simpler with [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock):

```cpp
// CTAD, equivalent to std::scoped_lock<std::mutex, std::mutex> lock(...)
std::scoped_lock lock(from.mtx, to.mtx);
```

`std::scoped_lock` is a replacement for `std::lock_guard` and has deadlock free locking built into the constructor, similar to using `std::lock`.

---

*See also [What's the best way to lock multiple std::mutex'es?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17113619/5740428)*

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed and very helpful explanations.  Based on what you explained, I've come to understand that when objects of std::unique_lock are passed to std::lock, the std::lock function calls the lock() method of each std::unique_lock object. This, in turn, locks the associated mutex. In this scenario, due to std::defer_lock, the mutex isn't locked directly upon the creation of the std::unique_lock object. Instead, it's locked via the std::lock function which is designed to handle deadlock-free scenarios. Is my understanding accurate?

Comment: @Sami yes, that sounds right.Keep in mind that `std::lock` will call a mixture of `lock()`, and `try_lock()` until it succeeds in locking all locks.