# Is there a facility to lock multiple mutexes in Rust while preventing deadlocking?

Tags: rust, mutex

Is there a C++ `std::lock()` like facility in Rust to prevent deadlocking in code like this:

```
type Type0 = Arc<Mutex<u8>>;
type Type1 = Arc<Mutex<u16>>;

fn foo(a: Type0, b: Type1) {
    let a_guard = a.lock().unwrap();
    let b_guard = b.lock().unwrap();
}

fn bar(a: Type0, b: Type1) {
    let b_guard = b.lock().unwrap();
    let a_guard = a.lock().unwrap();
}
```

If `foo` is called by thread-0 and `bar` by thread-1 there is a chance of deadlock. Is there something, hopefully variadic because I can have more than 2, to help me with this or am I all on my own verifying the correctness of order of locking?

From [the documentation for `std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock):

> Locks the given `Lockable` objects `lock1`, `lock2`, `...`, `lockn` using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know how `std::lock` works, but (unless you follow mmstick's answer in lumping the data together and locking/unlocking it at once) I don't see how you could ever *guarantee* no deadlocks. Sure, you could write a macro to do them in the right order -- but then you've just mutated the problem of *checking that you always lock them in the right order* into the barely-easier problem of *checking that you always use the macro and never call .lock() directly*. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, Rust does not have a function equivalent to C++'s `std::lock`.

Based on the fact that it doesn't seem to be in the [`std::sync` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/index.html) and Googling brings up nothing useful, I'm pretty confident in this assertion.

Why not? Well, if I may editorialize a bit, `std::lock` isn't as broadly useful as you might hope. Deadlock avoidance is nontrivial and every algorithm will have plausible corner cases that result in poor performance or even livelock. There is no one-size-fits-all deadlock avoidance algorithm.¹ (See [Is std::lock() ill-defined, unimplementable, or useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18520983/3650362)) Putting a deadlock-avoiding `lock` function in the standard library suggests that it's a good *default* choice, and perhaps encourages its use without regard for its implementation. Most real-life applications probably would do as well with a simpler (and less general-purpose) algorithm.

There are crates that provide deadlock avoidance by other means. For instance, [tracing-mutex](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-mutex) provides locking types that create a dependency graph at runtime and will panic instead of deadlocking if the dependency graph contains a cycle. [parking_lot](https://lib.rs/crates/parking_lot) has an experimental `deadlock_detection` feature (but I'm not sure how it works). Curiously, I didn't find any crates that provide a C++ `std::sort` equivalent with backing off.

**Anyway**, nothing stops you writing your own "backing off" algorithm to solve this problem; it's just not part of the standard library.

---

¹ In fairness, you could make the same argument for other functions Rust does have, like `[T]::sort`. But there are many applications where sorting is not a bottleneck and any reasonably fast algorithm is good enough. Deadlock avoidance is both less likely to be necessary in general, and more likely to be performance-sensitive when it does appear.

Answer (score 6):

This is easily solved if the `Mutex` is a tuple with the contained values, so that locking the tuple locks both values simultaneously.

```
let tuple_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new((A, B)));
```

Comment: Excellent point, but might want to retain the flexibility of independent values.

Comment: We can view tuple is just a single type - so that is basically Mutexing a single type. What i am looking for though is a solution to different Mutexs. For granularity you might not want to _always_ lump them into a single tuple/type - then you are sacrificing cases where they could function independent of each other which abound in my code. It's really a difference betwen `Arc<Mutex`ing the whole `struct` vs `Arc<Mutex`ing individual fields. The latter gives much finer control and my question was about that - is there a facility similar to `std::lock` of c++.

Comment: Does this really allow us to lock the mutextes simultaneously, or are they in reality locked one after the other? If so, what order are the mutextes unlocked in?

Comment: @SimonElliott There is only one `Mutex` in this solution; it is used to lock a compound value. The values are locked simultaneously because they are controlled by the same mutex.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue where I have a mutex for every logged in user. When two users interact, I need to lock both users. To solve this I needed some sorting mechanism to order the locks. Since I'm using `Arc<Mutex<User>>` I wrote a utility function to handle it:

```rust
async fn ordered_lock<'a, T>(
    m1: &'a Arc<Mutex<T>>,
    m2: &'a Arc<Mutex<T>>,
) -> (MutexGuard<'a, T>, MutexGuard<'a, T>) {
    let l1;
    let l2;
    if Arc::as_ptr(m1) > Arc::as_ptr(m2) {
        l2 = m2.lock().await;
        l1 = m1.lock().await;
    } else {
        l1 = m1.lock().await;
        l2 = m2.lock().await;
    };
    (l1, l2)
}
```

It'd work the same with non-async mutex,