# what are the use cases for std::unique_lock::release?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking

In what situations would one use the `release` method of `std::unique_lock` ?
I made the mistake of using the `release` method instead of the `unlock` method and it took a while to understand why the following code wasn't working.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex mtx;

void foo()
{    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << "in critical section\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    lock.release();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(foo));

    for (std::thread& t : threads)
        t.join();
}
```

Comment: Aside: in this case you want a `lock_guard`, not a `unique_lock`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.release()` is useful when you want to keep the mutex locked until some other object/code decides to unlock it... for example, if you were calling into a function that needed the mutex locked and would unlock it itself at a certain point in that function's processing, where that function accepts only a `std::mutex&` rather than a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&&`.  (Conceptually similar to the uses for smart pointer release functions.)

Answer (score 7):

There's a good use for it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525010/576911) where ownership of the locked state is explicitly transferred from a function-local `unique_lock` to an external entity (a by-reference *Lockable* parameter).

This concrete example is typical of the use:  To transfer ownership of the locked state from one object (or even type) to another.